# how to make discord bot be case insensitive and listen to pings same time?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or['S!', 's!'], case_insensitive=True)
```

Above is my code it just gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or['S!', 's!'], case_insensitive=True)
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
 
KeyboardInterrupt

```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's

```py
commands.when_mentioned_or(['S!', 's!'])
```

You have to add the normal brackets like in any other function

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('s!'), case_insensitive=True)
```